# Unnumbered subfigure captions with line stretching

Tags: captions, subcaption

I'm trying to caption some subfigures with a label, but I'm also trying to slightly stretch the text of the subfigures. It seems when I apply these two pieces of code together, I get an error. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{font={stretch=1.3}} %This appears incompatable

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
            \caption*{Unnumbered sub-image caption} %This appears incompatable
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. I forget to add the package {setspace} at the beginning.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}

\usapackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{font={stretch=1.3}} %This appears incompatable

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
            \caption*{Unnumbered sub-image caption} %This appears incompatable
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```